# Wordpress: Integration Mailchimp Without Plugin Bad Request 400 Ajax URL

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, mailchimp

I am trying to integrate with mailchimp with ajax request without using a plugin and I have error 400 bad request. Code below is written in vanilla JS for Ajax and the function of integration with mailchimp.
note: i don't want to use jquery in ajax, that's why i used vanilla javascript

the error appears on the console as: POST http://local.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)

**Ajax Vanilla JS**

```
// Objeto com todos os campos e propriedades dentro do formulário
const form = {
    email: document.getElementById('email'),
    submit: document.getElementById('btn-submit-newsletter-idinheiro'),
    messages: document.getElementById('newsletter-idinheiro-messages'),
}

// Evento do submit do formulário
form.submit.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Instanciando Requisição AJAX
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onload = () => {
        let responseObject = null;

        try {
            responseObject = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('Could not parse JSON');
        }

        if (responseObject) {
            handleResponse(responseObject);
        }
    };

    // Obter valores do formulário digitado pelo usuário
    const requestData = `email=${form.email.value}`;

    request.open('POST', object_name.ajax_url); // O object_name é uma variável importada pela função wp_localize_script como array dentro de functions.php
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    request.send(requestData);
    
    // Função de retorno das mensagens obtidos dos campos validados pelo PHP a serem inseridas no front
    const handleResponse = (responseObject) => {

        // Limpa elemento atualizando com o novo valor
        while (form.messages.firstChild) {
            form.messages.removeChild(form.messages.firstChild);
        }

        // Função de resposta das mensagens
        const responseMessages = () => {
            responseObject.messages.forEach((message) => {
                const element = document.createElement('span');
                element.textContent = message;
                form.messages.appendChild(element);
            });
            
            form.messages.style.display = 'block';
        }
        
        // Condicional mensagens
        if (responseObject.ok) {
            responseMessages();
            form.messages.classList.add('newsletter__messages--success');
            form.messages.classList.remove('newsletter__messages--error');

        } else {
            responseMessages();
            form.messages.classList.add('newsletter__messages--error');
            form.messages.classList.remove('newsletter__messages--success');
        }
    }
});
```

**Functions.php - Enqueue Script**

```
function idinheiro_scripts() {
    // JS
    wp_enqueue_script( 'all-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/all.min.js', NULL, '', true );
    
    // Localize SCRIPT
    wp_localize_script('all-js', 'object_name', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    ));
}
```

**Functions.php - Integration Mailchimp**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_subscribe_user', 'subscribe_user_to_mailchimp');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_subscribe_user', 'subscribe_user_to_mailchimp');
 
function subscribe_user_to_mailchimp() {
    check_ajax_referer('subscribe_user', 'security');
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $audience_id = getenv('MAIN_LIST_ID_MAILCHIMP');
    $api_key = getenv('API_KEY_MAILCHIMP');
    $data_center = substr($api_key,strpos($api_key,'-')+1);
    $url = 'https://'. $data_center .'.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/'. $audience_id .'/members';
    $auth = base64_encode( 'user:' . $api_key );
    $arr_data = json_encode(array(
        'email_address' => $email,
        'status' => 'subscribed' //pass 'subscribed' or 'pending'
    ));
 
    $response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'headers' => array(
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Authorization' => "Basic $auth"
            ),
            'body' => $arr_data,
        )
    );
 
    if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
       $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
       echo "Something went wrong: $error_message";
    } else {
        $status_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response );
        switch ($status_code) {
            case '200':
                echo $status_code;
                break;
            case '400':
                $api_response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true );
                echo $api_response['title'];
                break;
            default:
                echo 'Something went wrong. Please try again.';
                break;
        }
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `action` to call WordPress ajax in your case action should be `subscribe_user`.

```
const requestData = `action=subscribe_user&email=${form.email.value}`;

request.open('POST', object_name.ajax_url); // O object_name é uma variável importada pela função wp_localize_script como array dentro de functions.php
request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
request.send(requestData);
```

Comment: can you share a screenshot of the ajax call showing how `requestData` is passing to ajax?

Comment: First, you are getting `403 forbidden` not `404 forbidden!` as you said in your comments.
can you share with me the screenshot of the network tab rather than the console with requestData is passing to ajax.

Comment: I just tested in my local and it's working fine.

Comment: As per your original question I answered it. you should more check by search `wordpress ajax 403 forbidden`